# Glom: spec that creates an array from a string

Tags: python, transformation, glom

In Python, given a dict in input as follows:

```py
input = {
    'foo': 'bar'
}
```

which glom spec should I use to transform it into an array with a single item?

```py
spec = ?
glom(input, spec)
# ['bar']
```

I can't find any reference for such a transformation in glom documentation

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `glom(input, ('foo', lambda t: [t]))` would work, or `glom(d.values(), [glom.T])`? Not sure if that fits your desire

Comment: @Wondercricket first one works just fine! The second one returns an array with every value, but in this case I just want the value of 'foo' to be in the destination array, thank you

Comment: @Federinkik Glad I could help! I'm posting the first option as an answer

Comment: @Wondercricket can you think of any spec that is a dict and doesn't make use of lambdas? I would like to serialize the spec in a JSON column in a Postgres DB

Comment: I'd have the play around with it and see what I can come up with

Comment: @Wondercricket thank you, sorry for the weird request, I just started to use glom a few days ago and I'm still figuring out how it works and if it fits my use case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240181/discussion-between-federinik-and-wondercricket).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on their [documentation](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snippets.html#data-driven-assignment), you can utilize `lambda` as a part of the `spec` argument:

```
import glom
input = {'foo': 'bar'}
foo = glom.glom(input, ('foo', lambda t: [t]))
print(foo)
>>> ['bar']
```